# VueJS component with DOM elements outside of $el

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm almost completely new to Vue and coming from a custom-built front-end framework that we've been using for some time.

Now we've started slowing rolling in Vue in our website and refactoring some of our old components, and I've run into a bit of a problem.

The question is: is there any way for a component to instantiate some DOM elements outside of its scope (for example at the end of )?

We need these bits to be outside of the components' container because, for example, in the case of dropdowns, they would be obscured when the one of its parent elements has `overflow: hidden;`

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting the same question in the Vue Forums, the solution seems to be an amazing component called [portal-vue](https://linusborg.github.io/portal-vue/).

[See the Forum reply here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/components-with-dom-outside-of-el/2576/4?u=tibineagu)